# Prove the integral of $\cot x$ is $-\ln|\csc x|+C$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, proof-verification

I know how to prove it to be $\ln|\sin x|+C$, but I do not know the method to prove it this way.

thanks

Comment: $\ln |\sin x|=\ln |\csc x|^{-1} =-\ln|\csc x|$.

Comment: Well $\frac{d}{dx} (-\ln |\operatorname{csc} x| + C)=\cot x$. That is proof.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate this by substitution. Notice that

$$\int \cot x \ \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

Make the substitution $u=\sin x$, which gives $\mathrm{d}u = \cos x \ \mathrm{d}x$. Hence:
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \ \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{1}{u} \ \mathrm{d}u = \ln|u|+c = \ln|\sin x| + c$$

A result that **you need to know by memory** is that
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{f}'(x)}{\mathrm{f}(x)} \ \mathrm{d}x = \ln|\mathrm{f}(x)| + c$$
You can varify this for yourself by making the substitution $u=\mathrm{f}(x)$, giving $\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{f}'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$:
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{f}'(x)}{\mathrm{f}(x)} \ \mathrm{d}x =  \int \frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u = \ln |u|+c=\ln|\mathrm{f}(x)|+c$$

Comment: I guess I do not understand how this reaches -ln|cscx|. I can see how it reaches ln|sinx|. Do I multiply cotx by -csc^2x/-csc^2x to get fprime over f? I need to be able to prove this long hand.  Thanks

Comment: I figured it out- multiply cotx by cscx/cscx and let u = cscx, as du = -cotxcscx dx.

Comment: @Cooper I'm sorry to see that you haven't found my answer helpful. You up-vote answers that you find helpful. You can up-vote by clicking the grey up-arrow. Remember that $\ln(a/b) = \ln a - \ln b$. In particular $\ln(1/a) = \ln 1 - \ln a = -\ln a$. We have $\csc x = 1/\sin$ and so 

$$\ln|\csc x| = \ln|1/\sin x| = \ln 1 - \ln |\sin x| = -\ln|\sin x|$$
If $\ln|\csc x| = -\ln|\sin x|$ then $\ln | \sin x| = -\ln|\csc x|$. You can also select your favorite answer by clicking the grey tick.